# How TO add a condition with flutter?

Tags: flutter, list, dart, if-statement, display

hello everyone I'm new with flutter I want to make condition for this code:

```
 BluetoothDevice.fromProto(protos.BluetoothDevice p)
//if (p.name== "xx")
      : id = new DeviceIdentifier(p.remoteId),
        name = p.name,
        type = BluetoothDeviceType.values[p.type.value];
```

```
` static Protos.BluetoothDevice from(BluetoothDevice device) {
        Protos.BluetoothDevice.Builder p = Protos.BluetoothDevice.newBuilder();
        p.setRemoteId(device.getAddress());
        String name = device.getName();
        if(name != null) {
            p.setName(name);
        }
```

I want make a condition like in the comment on the code below.
Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: It's not really clear what you are asking. What do you want to do on that condition?

Comment: @Ivo I want to return juste devices with name like 'XXX'. like `if (p.name== "xx") {}`

Comment: You are showing a constructor. Simply don't call it when you don't want it?

Comment: @Ivo How I didn't get it?

Comment: Show us where you use `BluetoothDevice.fromProto`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to change

```
    .map((s) => s.map((p) => new BluetoothService.fromProto(p)).toList())
```

to

```
    .map((s) => s.map((p) => new BluetoothService.fromProto(p)).where((p) => p.name== "xx").toList())
```

Comment: I got `The getter 'name' isn't defined for the type 'BluetoothService'.`

Comment: @rania ah, I assumed the code you showed was from `BluetoothDevice.fromProto`, not `BluetoothService.fromProto`. The code you showed doesn't even deal with `BluetoothDevice`

Comment: @rania You are not making any sense to me sorry. Maybe someone else can help you better

Comment: I updated my question please check it maybe this could be helpful